# Do I need RenderBufferObject in my FBO to render-to-texture with alpha channel perserved?

Tags: opengl

On Windows 7 (with an nVidia GTS 450), my framebuffer seems to be locked at having 0 alpha bits. This means when I call `glCopyTexSubImage2D` to render-to-texture the texture will always be opaque.

I'm writing an alternative version of my OpenGL code that will use FBOs to render-to-texture (rather than `glCopyTexSubImage2D`) in the hopes that that will fix the issue of alpha getting discarded.

If I use a FBO, do I need to also allocate my own framebuffer (a RenderBufferObject)? My knowledge of FBOs is a little lacking, but my understanding is that if I don't provide a render buffer storage, and merely just attach a texture, it will use the existing framebuffer (which has no alpha bits) and thus my texture will still be completely opaque.

**edit:** some snafu with my project settings was the reason my alpha bits was being locked at 0, I'm now successfully getting 8 bits of alpha with `glCopyTexSubImage2D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textures and renderbuffers mostly serve the same purpose as FBO attachments. You can use a texture or a renderbuffer as your color attachment, a texture or a renderbuffer as your depth attachment, etc.

The main difference is that after you finished rendering to the FBO, if you used textures as attachments, you can use them for sampling like any other texture. If you used a renderbuffer, that option is not available. A renderbuffer cannot be used for anything else than serve as a FBO target. The only thing you can do with it afterwards is copy it to another render target, using `glBlitFramebuffer()`.

Renderbuffers are therefore mostly useful for buffers that you will not use anymore after you finished the FBO rendering. Often, that's true for the depth buffer. For most interesting 3D rendering, you will need a depth buffer for your FBO rendering. But in many cases, you will simply discard the content of the depth buffer once the rendering is done.

You might ask why you would ever use renderbuffers if you can do the same thing with texture attachments, and more. There can be a couple of advantages:

- Renderbuffers can do more than texture attachments in some OpenGL versions. For example, ES 3.0 supports multisampled renderbuffers, but not multisampled textures.
- Some hardware architectures have multiple memory layouts, where one might be more efficient for render targets, and another one more efficient for sampling. If you allocate a renderbuffer, the driver knows that it will only be used as a render target, and might be able to use a more efficient memory layout for the purpose.
- The APIs for creating renderbuffers are simpler.

That covers the general background. For your specific case:

- No, if you render to a texture (i.e. use a texture as the color attachment of your FBO), you do not also need a renderbuffer for the same purpose.
- You may need to create a renderbuffer to be used as the depth buffer for your FBO rendering. To do this, you create a renderbuffer with `glRenderbufferStorage()`, and use `glFramebufferRenderbuffer()` to attach it as the `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` of the FBO. Note that the depth buffer of the default framebuffer is **not** used for FBO rendering, so this is required if you need a depth buffer for the FBO rendering.

BTW, your video card should definitely support alpha bits in the framebuffer. Under Windows, you can request alpha bits by setting the `cAlphaBits` field in the `PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR` structure. The typical value to use for this field is 8 if you want alpha bits in the framebuffer.

Comment: [cAlphaBits is ignored on Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368826%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Even with setting that (to 8), `glGetIntegerv` tells me that my framebuffer still has no alpha bits. And indeed the texture remains opaque.

Comment: @Mr.Smith: That is not true: "Please notice carefully, as documented above, that certain pixel format properties are not supported in the current generic implementation. The generic implementation is the Microsoft GDI software implementation of OpenGL. Hardware manufacturers may enhance parts of OpenGL, and may support some pixel format properties not supported by the generic implementation." Every implementation expcept microsoft's GDI renderer supports alpha channels on windows since aeons.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that I used framebuffers with alpha bits at least as far back as Windows XP and NV34 GPUs. And I just confirmed that they are still supported on my current laptop, which runs Windows 8.1. In the configuration I tested (Intel HD 4600 graphics), I got a pixelformat with cAlphaBits=8 when not even requesting alpha bits.

Comment: @derhass I've even attempted to disable Aero and request only 24 bits of color, and 8 bits of alpha, I still get 0 bits of alpha on my OpenGL context. I think you're confusing texture formats with framebuffer formats; my textures are successfully being created with an 8 bit alpha channel and are successfully rendering with blending, but my framebuffer has no alpha bits.

Comment: @Mr.Smith: no, I'm not confusing textures and framebuffers. Are you sure you even get a context via nvidia's ICD? You might have some fallback to the GDI renderer, after all.

Comment: Get a copy of OpenGL Extension Viewer, and look at the list of available pixel formats. On my machine, I could not find an accelerated pixel format without alpha for either the Intel (HD 46000) or the NVIDIA (GT 740M) GPU. The only 24-bit formats are unaccelerated. You really might have something in your pixel format selection that prevents you from getting accelerated formats.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I cycled through the 482 pixel formats on my nVidia GTS 450 as the current renderer, not a single one had `WGL_TRANSPARENT_ARB` set to `True`. I'm presuming that's the flag you were looking for, since `WGL_ALPHA_BITS_ARB` was not listed anywhere.

Comment: It looks like the tool includes the alpha bits in `WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB`. Where it says 32, that's 24 bits of RGB and 8 bits of alpha.